# Equation is not centered

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, positioning

I can't put my equation in the center, i don't know if is related to be using the srcbook package.

[image: equation]

I tried using the amsmath package, the nccmath package and fleqn command, also i used the align* command, but the equation is always as you can see in the image.

What can i do?

Comment: Please post a minimal working example of LaTeX code that generates the problem behavior you're looking to fix. The code should begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works without problems.  If you want to have your equations centred, do *not* use the `fleqn` option.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
I can't align this equation
\begin{align*}
  a &= b \\
    &= c
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you,  there was a hidden fleqn in the document class, that was my problem.

Comment: @LenaVonEngel - Are you sure the `scrbook` document class sets the option `fleqn`?

Comment: @Mico I think OP was using some custom class wrapping `scrbook`.

Comment: @Mico It was, at least in the template i was using for.